# Why is some data missing in ggplot2 stacked bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a `dput()` of a subset of my data as an example:

```
test <- structure(list(trt = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
                               "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"
        ), parameter_name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", 
                              "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        values = c(12.2, 45.5, 24.7, 11, 6.5, 12.2, 49, 22.8, 10.1, 6, 12, 47.7, 25.2, 9.3, 6)),
        row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to plot a stacked bar chart like this, only parameter_name "A" doesn't show.

```
ggplot(test, aes(trt, values, fill = parameter_name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean")
```

[image]

Setting position = "dodge2" suggests that A is there,

```
ggplot(test, aes(trt, values, fill = parameter_name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean", position = "dodge2")
```

[image]

but I cant work out why it isn't showing in the stacked version?  Changing the position to "stack" also shows A, but I don't want the values as %

```
ggplot(test, aes(trt, values, fill = parameter_name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean", position = "stack")
```

I also checked if it was just a problem with the scale, but "A" is still not visible

```
ggplot(test, aes(trt, values, fill = parameter_name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60))
```

Can someone point out my mistake for me?

Comment: `position = "stack"` seems to work. Not sure why the default `position = "identity"` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (`position = "identity"`) each bar is displayed on top of each other. Since group A is the first to be plotted and is smaller than the other groups it is masked by them.

The answer is in your question: you need to use `position = "stack"`:

```
ggplot(test, aes(trt, values, fill = parameter_name)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean", position = "stack")
```

The values displayed are not %, it's just because the sum of your 5 mean values equals to 100